onPressed "invalid constant value" error in Flutter
There appears to be nothing wrong with the code I have for my ElevatedButton, but It's giving me this error:
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () { },
          child: Text('TextButton'),  
        )


This is even posted from the official Flutter website.
Any idea why it's doing this?

Correct it was that

It's suspected that your button is a child of a widget that's marked as constant widget, if so, just remove const keyword from parents of that button.
That's because onPressed() can't be declared on a constant scope.
